# Use Expander Control for displaying nested datagrid

Tags: .net, wpf, datagrid, expander

We are creating a WPF application in which we have to display nested datagrid. For this, we are using expander control. But, what happen is, our internal datagrid which is displaying on clicking of expander button, gets hidden behind our Main/Parent datagrid.

Following is the XAML code for datagrid:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding abc}">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
       <DataGridTemplateColumn Width="*" Header="column1">
          <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
             <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding item}"/>
                    <Expander>                                                            
                         <Canvas>
                           <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Path=xyz}">
                              <DataGrid.Columns>
                                  <DataGridTextColumn Header="column1"></DataGridTextColumn>
                                  <DataGridTextColumn Header="column1">
                              </DataGrid.Columns>
                            </DataGrid>
                         </Canvas>
                     </Expander>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
         </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
     </DataGridTemplateColumn>
</DataGrid>
```

Any idea to fix the above issue is highly appreciable.

Answer (score 0):

try to suppress the canvas

```
    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding abc}" >
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Width="*" Header="column1">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding item}"/>
                            <Expander IsExpanded="True">
                                    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Path=xyz}">
                                        <DataGrid.Columns>
                                            <DataGridTextColumn Header="column1"/>
                                            <DataGridTextColumn Header="column1"/>
                                        </DataGrid.Columns>
                                    </DataGrid>
                            </Expander>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

if it doesn't work can you please send a datacontext example  that populate the datagrid

Comment: Thanks Pansoul, but we had tried above approach as well. Still no success got. We developed a sample application for the same. Kindly go through with following link : 'https://skydrive.live.com/?cid=862cc12c7e381559&id=862CC12C7E381559!118'